# How to break out and return an object from a recursion after meeting a certain condition is met

Tags: java, recursion

I have a recusrion function where i want to return the object as soon as certain condition is met . The function looks like this .

```
GroupNavigationItemSRO getCategorySpecificNavItem(List<GroupNavigationItemSRO> items,String url) {
        GroupNavigationItemSRO sro = new GroupNavigationItemSRO();
        if(items != null && !items.isEmpty()){
            for(GroupNavigationItemSRO item : items) {
                if(item.getUrl().equals(url)) {
                    LOG.info("Found Specific Url");
                    return item;            
                }
                else
                getCategorySpecificNavItem(item.getChildren(),url);
               }
            }
        return null;
    }
```

Now the function returns null and i get why its happening despite meeting the criteria .How to avoid that and end the recursion as soon as the url is found.

Comment: And make sure that `item.getUrl()` returns `String` and not `URL`.

Comment: @naomik: You're right (of course). It's complicated enough I'll post an answer.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I look forward to it ^_^

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is stop looking when you've found it, but recurse until you do.

The main problem with your existing code is that the recursive call's return value is ignored. Instead, you want to look at that return value and, if it's not `null`, return it; you're done:

```
for(GroupNavigationItemSRO item : items) {
    if(item.getUrl().equals(url)) {
        LOG.info("Found Specific Url");
        return item;            
    }
    else {
        GroupNavigationItemSRO itemFromChild = getCategorySpecificNavItem(item.getChildren(),url);
        if (itemFromChild != null) {
            // Found!
            return itemFromChild;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Continuation passing style would be pretty sick for this. I don't think I've ever seen anything like that in Java tho. Have you?

Comment: @naomik: I'm not sure I know what you mean by "continuation passing style"? (Sounds like a term I should know...)

Comment: Uh oh, be prepared to literally have your brain turned inside out... You can't blame me for this...

Comment: Just looked it up -- I know the kind of thing. :-) No reason you couldn't do that in Java these days, what with lambdas and such... But I don't think we need it here, simple recursion's sufficient.

Comment: TJ, here's a little thing I wrote to show how CPS could work in JavaScript – [https://repl.it/Elqb/1](https://repl.it/Elqb/1) – I have no Idea how you'd do this in Java tho